# How to determine if a ARXML file is of CAN network or Ethernet network in AUTOSAR standards

Tags: xml, ethernet, can-bus, autosar

So I am totally new to this automotive field so please correct me if I am wrong in any terminologies.
So I have this ARXML file of AUTOSAR standard and I want to determine it is of what network type>
is it of CAN network or Ethernet or FLexRay or SumIP.

Is there any specific tag from the ARXML which can help to determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine ARXML file is based on which Bus standard, Search for Cluster type which can give indication for same.
If you find "CAN-CLUSTER" then CAN protocol or "ETHERNET-CLUSTER" then its based on Ethernet protocol.

Answer (score 2):

ARXML is the general AUTOSAR exchange format. It can express several things in one file or split over multiple files.

Regarding "networking", it can contain a whole system in one file, compared to DBC files. So instead of 2 or more DBC files, all can be contained in a single SystemDescription (see also **AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate**).

The main entry point into a proper `SystemDescription` / `SystemExtract` or `EcuExtract` is actually the `System`, which should have a list of all so called FibexElements used/refered to by the system. These `FibexElement`s are CommunicationClusters, EcuInstances, Frames, Pdus (in different kinds), ISignals and ISignalGroups, ...

The `category` attribute of a `System` actually tells you, if you have a `SYSTEM_DESCRIPTION`, a `SYSTEM_EXTRACT`, an `ECU_EXTRACT`, or just an `ABSTRACT_SYSTEM_DESCRIPTION` .. in the file.

You can look for Clusters (CanCluster, EthernetCluster, FlexrayCluster), EcuInstances (which have e.g. multiple CanCommunicationControllers and CanCommunicationConnectors, which refer to the CanCommunicationController). CommunicationChannelConnectors are refrenced from a PhysicalChannel below a Cluster.

To understand, how the information is comtained in the ARXML file, you should actually read the AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate.

BTW. There is no SumIP as "network". If you mean SOME/IP, this is not a network, but some higher layer protocol over Ethernet.

Also keep in mind, when you have two DBC files, the network there gets the name of the DBC file. In ARXML files and due to the splitable concept, if you have 2 ARXML files and each file has a CanCommunicationCluster named `CanCluster`, the AUTOSAR tools will usually merge them together into a single `CanCluster` due to the same name. So, if you have 2 separate clusters, give them unique names, even though they are in two separate ARXML files.